# MacBook Pro M1 starts for a few seconds, displaying the Apple logo, before abruptly shutting down again

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

Here's a brief rundown of the issue:

The MacBook Pro shuts down without any warning.
When I attempt to charge it, the charging indicator doesn't light up, and the battery doesn't seem to charge.
Occasionally (dozens of minutes or more), the laptop starts for a few seconds, displaying the Apple logo, before abruptly shutting down again. While the short reboot the charger indicator lights up then turn off when the mac turns off

MacBook Pro M1

Comment: Have you tried a different charger (assuming your problem is with the MagSafe), or tried powering via USB-C?

Comment: the charger is fine and working.  i'll try another on but honeslty I don't suspect the charger.

Comment: Well, it could be the MagSafe cable. At least you can detach that and put a USB-C cable in its place to check charging via a different port. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102397

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store or other authorised repair shop for a diagnosis.